# What will be the possible causes for the 1st code fragment to output differently than 2nd and 3rd?

Tags: c++, global-variables

This is an excerpt from Insertion sort program. Below are given three code fragments, which are different version of same function, and ought to give same output; unfortunately, only the 2nd and 3rd code fragments give the expected output. Why does code fragment 1 act differently?

```
int find_smallest_index(int get_array[],int size,int left_index)    //1st        
{   
    int index_of_smallest_value;
    for(int right_index=left_index+1;right_index<size;right_index++)
      {
        if(get_array[right_index]<get_array[left_index])
        {index_of_smallest_value=right_index;}
      }
    return index_of_smallest_value;
 }


int find_smallest_index(int get_array[],int size,int left_index)   //2nd         
{   

    for(int right_index=left_index+1;right_index<size;right_index++)
    {
        if(get_array[right_index]<get_array[left_index]) 
        {left_index=right_index;}
    }
    return left_index;
}



int find_smallest_index(int get_array[],int size,int left_index)   //3rd           
{   int index_of_smallest_value=left_index;
    for(int right_index=left_index+1;right_index<size;right_index++)
    {
        if(get_array[right_index]<get_array[index_of_smallest_value]) 
        {index_of_smallest_value=right_index;}
    }
    return index_of_smallest_value;
}
```

Comment: The first example returns an uninitialized result if the loop never executes. I mean index_of_smallest_value will not be set if left_index+1 is not less than size.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- The first fragment defines the uninitialized variable `index_of_smallest_value` in the function, sets it for some condition, and returns it. It's good in the sense that it's returning stuff based on function args or local vars, but it has a problem if the condition is never true.
- The second & third fragment differ from the first in that, if the condition is never true, they return the value of some global variable. They have the opposite strengths & weaknesses from it.

---

You might consider redesigning the function so that it has both attributes - it relies only on inputs, but it always returns well-defined outputs.

Answer (score 1):

index_of_smallest_value in the first case is not initialized, so when the for loop is not executed you have unexoected result.